# ngx-bootstrap typeahead observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables, ngx-bootstrap

So I have a a typeahead input field that looks like this:

```
<input formControlName="segment"
              [typeahead]="segments"
              (typeaheadLoading)="segmentsLoading($event)"
              (typeaheadNoResults)="segmentsNoResults($event)"
              (typeaheadOnSelect)="segmentOnSelect($event)"
              typeaheadOptionsLimit="10"
              typeaheadMinLength="3"
              typeaheadWaitMs="300"
              [typeaheadItemTemplate]="customSegmentTemplate"
              class="form-control">
```

And an Observable which helps me get the suggestions in typeahead.

```
this.segments = Observable.create((observer: any) => observer.next(this.segments))
  .mergeMap((number: string) => this.suggestionsService.getSegmentSuggestions(this.editForm.get('segment').value);
```

My problem is that the Observable sends a request even when my input field value length is less than 3 even if I have set `typeaheadMinLength="3"`. This happens when user types in a value and then deletes some of the characters quickly (quicker than my debounce time) and then tries to enter a new value. My API for suggestions fails when it recieves input value with length less than 3 and then my application breaks and I have to refresh the page to make it work again. I have tried to set debounce time to 0 and I didnt have this issue then, but that is a bad practice and it sends too many requests to my API. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I added catch block like this
 `this.segments = Observable.create((observer: any) => observer.next(this.segments))
      .mergeMap((number: string) => this.suggestionsService.getSegmentSuggestions(this.editForm.get('segment').value))
      .catch((error: any) => {
        return [];
      });`

This solved my problem for now but I am sure there is a better solution than this.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Simon I solved it like in the comment above, and it is working at least until I find a more elegant solution. But more elegant solution is yet to be found.

Comment: Have you looked at interceptors in the new Angular HttpClient?

Comment: @ksimonson10 I have looked at it now that you mentioned it, but what version of angular HttpClient are you thinking of? I read somewhere that (with version 4.3) I cannot only apply the interceptor to certain requests instead of globally and that is what I need.

Comment: @banana I haven’t implemented it myself, planning to soon, but I think you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch of a work around that could help until they fix the control:

Pipe a filter operator before your observable fires the service call:

```
this.segments = Observable.create((observer: any) => observer.next(this.segments))
    .pipe(filter(number => number.length >= YOUR_MIN_LENTH_LIMIT),
    .mergeMap((number: string) => this.suggestionsService.getSegmentSuggestions(this.editForm.get('segment').value));
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `[typeaheadMinLength]="3" instead of typeaheadMinLength="3"`. When you assign it like `typeaheadMinLength="3"`, it becomes a string assignment.

You can use [`typeaheadWaitMs]="500"`, it will invoke api call after 500 MS of user input. Which is like behaves like debounce.

Comment: This did not work for me. It still sent a request to suggestionsService when input length was 1.